# Override struct field tags on imported structs

Tags: go

I have a third party client library ([Sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama)) that exposes [a configuration struct](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/e42dc76/config.go).

I want to reference that struct directly from my configuration struct:

```
type MyConfig struct {
  Sarama sarama.Config
}
```

I am using [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to marshal my configuration. Marshalling `MyConfig` with go-yaml panics because `sarama.Config` contains a field (`Partitioner`) that is of type `func` and the yaml parser doesn't know how to `Marshal` a `func`.

A way of preventing this panic would be to tell go-yaml to ignore this field (using the tag `yaml:"-"` on the field) but I am unable to set tags on a struct that isn't defined in my code.

Is there an elegant go way to include this configuration in my own configuration and not cause the go-yaml marshaller to panic? Should I try and override the tag or should I copy the struct into my own code and write a converter?

Comment: You cannot override the tag as you already noted, so I'm not sure what you're actually asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always had problems with `go-yaml`. The library is not in a good design. However it is the most effective tool at hand, at least for now.

There is some way to hide from `encoding/json` but I tested it does not work for `go-yaml`. However, `go-yaml` does provide a way to extend its capacity (though it is very awkward).

As I see in your code, that `Partitioner` is of type `PartitionerConstructor`, a custom type, so you can make `PartitionerConstructor` implents `yaml.Marshaler` interface:

```
func (PartitionerConstructor) MarshalYAML() (interface{},error) {
        return nil,nil
}
```

Note that it will generate a `Partitioner: null` line, but it will get around from panic.

Comment: Good to know.  I didn't know about `MarshalYAML()`. This does have the same problem as above though because I can't define a method on a struct that is defined in another package.